# Resolving same key for different records among multiple .bib databases

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, jabref

I am working on several `.bib` databases, like `first.bib`, `second.bib`, `third.bib`, etc.

Among these bib files, same key existed for different records, like an author wrote two papers within one year, and the keys generated for them are same, let's say `authorname2018`, but actually there are different papers.

The setting in preference can only solve the issue within one `.bib` file, 
[image]

so my question is how to generate different keys among multiple `.bib` files when importing records, without merging these `.bib` files into one `.bib` file?

Comment: On what level do you want to generate different keys? Do you want to configure JabRef to make sure that there are no duplicate keys across several files? Do you want to merge the `.bib` files into one large `.bib` file and want to avoid duplicates there? Or do you want your duplicates to be handled on the BibTeX/Biber side (I think that is not possible).

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I want to have unique keys among multiple `.bib` files. I don't want to merge these multiple `.bib` files. In current situation, I have same keys for different records within these `.bib` files. I hope jabref can automatically generate different keys in the future when I import new records. Hope my question is clear now.

Comment: JabRef is able to generate keys on import, but obviously only per bib file. Each bib file is a unique library. Libraries are independent of each other. It's not possible to have this among multiple libraries

Comment: Since the question is about JabRef and general `.bib` files and not the specific packages `natbib` and `biblatex` I have removed those tags. I guess it is not surprising that the function you are looking for is not yet implemented as usually `.bib` files are kept independent of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite obvious: As the default pattern `[auth][year]` of the BibTeX key generator could be duplicated in any other file, but JabRef have no way to check that, the ball is in your court: You must provide another pattern, ensuring  that will produce always unique keys. For instance:

- `[auth][year][firstpage]` or  if this is not enough ...
- `[authorIni][year][firstpage]`. This one use the first 5 characters of the first author’s last name, and the last name initials of the remaining authors. But if this is not enough (!) add also a  `[shorttitle]` or the `[keyword3]`. See the help of the program. There are more options...

But if you already used `[auth][year]` it could be hard check how each key have changed. And long keys are hard to remember. So another approach is construct the key based in the database, for example using `[auth][year]F` for  first.bib, `[auth][year]S` for second.bib, and so on. Then you can predict exactly how the keys have changed. And it is still a handy key.

As far as I know, the pattern preferences are global for all databases, i.e., you cannot store a particular pattern for a particular database, but as you can re-generate all the keys in a second, whenever you want, change the preferences seem a very insignificant issue.

And well, ... another option is merge the files. You do not like that but IHMO the best option, as generate the same simple and unique `[auth][year]` keys for all the references. And you can have still the source identified as keyword, for instance.

It is worth to note that biblatex can print subsets of cited references based in a keyword, so this is not a good reason to split a database.

JabRef could also work with these subsets easily, simply with a search of something as `keywords=SecondFile`, so why split it?

But if you want split it anyway, once selected the references in JabRef (with this search or in any other way), is as simple as <kbd>Export selected entries</kbd> option of the <kbd>File</kbd> menu., so merge the databases should not be a problem. Just make a backup and test it!  `;)`

Comment: Great explanation of the philosophy underpinning `Jabref`, and I will not split `.bib` for one project any more.